# Is there a way to disable connector in Dropwizard configuration file?

Tags: java, dropwizard

Due to environmental constraints there is no way to run both HTTP/HTTPS connectors on different ports. There is not easy way to use different config files either. Because of that it is required to enable disable HTTP/HTTPS connector based on the program arguments.

The way I'm doing it is implementing `ConfigurationSourceProvider` with Mustache templating engine and based on incoming parameters add/remove required connectors.

```
server:
  ....
  applicationConnectors:
    {{#httpsEnabled}}
    - type: https
      port: ${application.port}
      ....
    {{/httpsEnabled}}
    {{^httpsEnabled}}
    - type: http
      port: ${application.port}
    {{/httpsEnabled}}
```

Another approach which I found is to use property overrides:
`dw.server.applicationConnectors[0].*` but this approach looks cumbersome because for HTTPS config there are a lot of params.

Is there a better way of doing this? Something like 'disable' flag for connectors? Or something similar to 'Spring Profiles'?

Comment: You described 2 working solutions, what is your question then? :) If you are looking for an official way to do it, then it is probably property overrides.

Comment: I was hoping to find something like 'disable' flag for connectors. Double checking if I missed something.

Comment: You could also manipulate list of connectors programmatically via access to `ServerFactory` in `Configuration`. So on app start you could check some env/system property and filter out not enabled connectors.

Comment: Do you know the best part of the workflow where this can be done?

Comment: Somewhere in your `io.dropwizard.Application#run` override method, for example.